# Symfony / doctrine insert related objects

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an entity "Order" this entity has an array of orderDetails (class: "OrderDetail").

I want to insert the Order Entity, including the orderDetails off the Order. Everything works fine except the "order_id" field in the OrderDetail table stays NULL.

Code for insert:

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
    $order = $form->getData();
    $this->om->persist($order);
    $this->om->flush($order);

    return $order;
}
```

Dump $order

```
object(Jds\ApiBundle\Entity\Order)[439]
  protected 'id' => null
  protected 'orderDate' => 
    object(DateTime)[611]
      public 'date' => string '2015-01-15 13:42:00' (length=19)
      public 'timezone_type' => int 3
      public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Paris' (length=12)
  protected 'orderDetails' => 
    object(Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection)[440]
      private '_elements' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => 
            object(Jds\ApiBundle\Entity\OrderDetail)[667]
              protected 'id' => null
              protected 'product' => 
                object(Jds\ApiBundle\Entity\Product)[736]
                  ...
              protected 'price' => float 1
              protected 'amount' => int 2
              protected 'order' => null
          1 => 
            object(Jds\ApiBundle\Entity\OrderDetail)[702]
              protected 'id' => null
              protected 'product' => 
                object(Jds\ApiBundle\Entity\Product)[749]
                  ...
              protected 'price' => float 1
              protected 'amount' => int 5
              protected 'order' => null
```

Order-entity:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=false)
     * @Serializer\Groups({"orderList"})
     */
    protected $orderDate;

    //protected $orderedBy;

    //protected $handledBy;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="OrderDetail", mappedBy="order", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @Serializer\Groups({"orderList"})
     **/
    protected $orderDetails;
```

OrderDetail-entity

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product")
     * @Serializer\Groups({"orderList"})
     */
    protected $product;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=4, scale=2)
     */
    protected $price;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=2)
     * @Serializer\Groups({"orderList"})
     */
    protected $amount;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Order", inversedBy="orderDetails", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="order_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     **/
    protected $order;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you generated your entity using Symfony, you should have an `addOrderDetail` method (or something like that) in your Order entity (if not, you can create it yourself). In that method, you have to especifically set the `Order` for those `OrderDetail` that you want to add to the order.

```
// Class Order
public function addOrderDetail(OrderDetail $orderDetail){
    $this->orderDetails->add($orderDetail);
    $orderDetail->setOrder($this);// Assign this order to $orderDetail object

    return $this;
}
```

Use it everytime you add an OrderDetail to the order. After a persist and flush of the order, the orderdetails should have the id of the parent Order in the DB.

This is due to the owning and inverse side doctrine concept. Doctrine will only check the owning side of the [associations](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html)

Comment: This is the correct answer, but I forgot the "'by_reference'  => false" setting in the form config so the setter was never used. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the JoinColumn annotation on the ManyToOne relationship.  See the [docs for more details](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-one-unidirectional).

In the OrderDetail entity change the code to:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Order", inversedBy="orderDetails", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @JoinColumn(name="order_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
protected $order;
```

Comment: My column names are the default doctrine settings so setting the name and referencedColumnName doesn't make any difference. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Your relation is correct. Problem is inside controller.

This link should help (saving related entities)

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#saving-related-entities

BTW instead use

```
     $order = $form->getData()
```

use

```
     $order = $form->handleRequest($request)
```